# My batch file isn’t executing the .jar file like it’s supposed to

Tags: java, jar, minecraft-forge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFbmn.jpg)I tried to run a jar file through a batch file, but it closes without opening the UI that is meant to run with the file.

I tried downloading Jarfix, but could not double-click to run the jar file in question. Instead, it did nothing. I also tried opening with javaw, but it also did nothing. I’ve done the same thing a year ago and it ran fine. I also tried updating the Java version to the latest one. The jar file was expected to run and open a UI. Please help

Comment: Looks like you've got a space in the path of the command. That's not going to fly without quoting it `javaw -jar "D:\foo\bar\path with space\x.jar"`

Comment: What happens when you run that command without the "start" at the beginning?

Comment: @g00se I quoted the path, but it still doesn’t work and doesn’t run the jar.

Comment: @f1sh it still doesn’t load the jar

Comment: Start by executing the command on its own, *manually* at the command line. Let us know what happens

Comment: Still the same issue. I press enter and it moves to the next command line without opening the ui.

Comment: When I run the same command in powershell, it returns “a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name ‘jar’.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `javaw`. Is it even installed? You might start with `java -jar`

Comment: It is installed. I set a path to the jre\bin folder

Comment: Is it probably because of a duplicate javaw installation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a duplicate java folder in Oracle->Java, which I promptly deleted.